# Sanitizing html with Angular DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, xss, innerhtml, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm using Angular 7 and I'm facing a problem with the sanitization system.

I'm trying to use the `innerHtml` directive to insert some Html code in my page. This code can contain html and style attributes.

Without using `this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myCssHtmlCode)`, the style attributes are removed.

When I'm using it, the javascript code is not removed.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep style and html but remove the javascript code.

Something like the code below would be perfect but does not exist.

`domSanitzer.sanitize([SecurityContext.HTML, SecurityContext.STYLE], myCssHtmlCode)`

Is there any other way to combine the SecurityContext types?

Thanks!